# Are unused classes compiled by Xcode when building an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dead-code

If something is not used in C++, it's not compiled at all. Is the same true for iPhone?
If I compile a program and there are unused classes or other stuff, will it be compiled or ignored?

Comment: The question you're asking is unclear? Are you asking if iOS code is compiled?

Comment: I mean, if I am to compile a program and there are unused classes or other stuff, will it be compiled or ignored?

Comment: I spotted the question! It's the 4th sentence: "Is the same true for iPhone."

Comment: Ah, that's a better question. Let's edit it and get it re-opened. Excellent question in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, are you comparing C++ to an iPhone? Can you also compare a pizza to the feeling of inescapable dread while you're at it?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am merely using C++ as a frame of reference as all my current experience is in C++. I admit I'm not the most diverse yet, but I'm trying to branch out.

Comment: @Ani, that's fine. Just so you know, dead code stripping is not a language feature, but a _compiler_ feature.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on your build settings.

Under your target build settings, then under "Linking" there is an option for "Dead Code Stripping". It defaults to yes for projects created with Xcode.

[image]

Here's a link to the build settings documentation from Apple (with an excerpt):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html

> DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING (Dead Code Stripping)
>
> Description: Boolean value.
>
> Specifies whether dead code is stripped from the binary.
>
> Prerequisite: $GCC_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = full
>
> Values:
>
> YES: Dead code is stripped from
> the binary when the prerequisite is met.
>
> NO: Dead code is not stripped
> from the binary.
>
> Default value: NO Companions: “GCC_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS
> (Level of Debug Symbols).” Prerequisite for:
> PRESERVE_DEAD_CODE_INITS_AND_TERMS

Note, the docs say the value defaults to NO, but Xcode project settings default the value to YES.

Comment: What about imported Packages with unused classes, structs or unused views in a variable?

Comment: Addition: I as thinking about Swift Packages.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that any resource that is added to a target will get compiled and/or copied to your application bundle at build time. To edit which files are built/copied, you can modify the settings in Xcode 4, by clicking on project, then your target. Under Build Phases, you can change the files as needed.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

There is also a setting for Dead Code Stripping under Build Settings. Here's what that looks like:

[image]

It defaults to yes, but if you want to disable it for some reason, that's how you'd do so.